# Latex error: Command \citename already defined. ...*{\citename}{\blx@citexpunct{citename}}

Tags: biblatex, compiling, compilation-error

I am try to compile my Latex file but I am getting this error during compilation:

**Update Error message:**

`! LaTeX Error: Command \citename already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.10472 ...*{\citename}{\blx@citexpunct{citename}}
Your command was ignored.`

This is my Latex file definitions:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
\end{filecontents*}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{svjour3}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sqcases}{%
\matrix@check\sqcases\env@sqcases
 }{%
\endarray\right.%
 }
\def\env@sqcases{%
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left\lbrack
\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}

\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, citetracker=true, maxcitenames=1, 
giveninits, terseinits, uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{2}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

   \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{lam2016nonparametric,
        title={Nonparametric eigenvalue-regularized precision or covariance 
         matrix estimator},
         author={Lam, Clifford},
         journal={The Annals of Statistics},
         volume={44},
         number={3},
         pages={928--953},
         year={2016},
    publisher={Institute of Mathematical Statistics},
    doi = {0.1214/15-AOS1393}
    }

   \end{filecontents}

  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
  \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

  \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
  \renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
  \DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

  \DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

  \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}

  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

  \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

  \renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon} 
  {\addcomma\space}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

  \DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}

  \DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
        \pertype{article}
        \step[fieldset=number, null]
    }
    }
    }

  \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
  \begin{document}
  .
  .
  .
  .
  \printbibliography
  \end{document}
```

Any idea about how can I fix this error ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Well, I don't see a `\documentclass` in your example. I don't see an end to your `\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}` either. It is no wonder your are getting errors. Are you sure the error you are reporting is coming from this code you provided us?

Comment: Your code can not be compilable, the documentclass is missing ...  What should `\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}` do as first line of code?

Comment: Sorry for this mistake, I forget to add these lines in this post. But it is exist in my latex file on my pc.

Comment: I add missing lines to the post. I forget add these lines here while try to shortner the code for posting. Sorry again for this mistake.

Comment: The problem with the particular error you report comes from your call `\usepackage{harvard}` and then later `biblatex`. The first defines `\citename` and when the second one tries to do the same, it issues an error. AFAIK, the both are incompatible, so if you intend to use biblatex, leave out `\usepackage{harvard}`.

Comment: @gusbrs I fixed the problem by removing `\usepackage{harvard}` since I am using biblatex as you said. Thank you very much for the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are loading `harvard` and latter `biblatex`. `harvard` is meant to work on a BibTeX setting for bibliography/citation, not with `biblatex`.

The problem you face with this particular error is that `harvard` has already defined `\citename` when you load `biblatex` which tries to define the same macro. So you get an error out of it.

In sum, if you intend to use `biblatex`, you should leave out `\usepackage{harvard}`.

Comment: I fix the problem. It was very useful tip. I will keep it in my mind for my next latext paper. Regards